# How to display data in a div based on user input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form that sends credits from one account to another via database.

When the user enters their ID number I want to display the user's name so they can be sure it is the right account.

Example :

Before :

[image]

After :

[image]

Comment: Nothing so far. I think you'll need ajax and I've never used it before.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to use Ajax. I'd recommend using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Then if you have some troubles, you can post your issue in detail.

Comment: 2 way data binding is great for this because you can manipulate a div and model. Angularjs and Reactjs are great  for this

Comment: It would be a good idea to check a couple of things (lenght of input, valid input, etc) before sending a request in order to minimize traffic. Also, it may be a good idea to cache some results, again to minimize traffic.

Comment: You absolutely do not want to display user names 'as the user types'. It simply makes no sense to look for a user name until you have the whole user ID. Apart from being pointless it will display info about other users to the current user which is a bad idea that has the potential to put you in prison for privacy law violation in the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an event listener to execute some code when the user enters some input.

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").addEventListener("input", function() {
  // The input just changed. Do something with it.
  
  // For example change the text in the div:
  document.getElementById("myOutput").innerText = this.value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" />

<div id="myOutput"></div>
```

Here's [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/nicovank/wxczq7a3/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do the searching on the server:

1. Find out when to check if you have a match (onKeyUp, onBlur, ... etc) and bind this event from your input to a function X
2. Create a function X that get the value of your input and sends an ajax quests with this value to your server (Example: www.server.com/userQuery?query=value)
3. On the server, make the route mentioned in the above point; This route will query the database for a entry containing the value, or part of the value (example: LIKE 'value%'). Only using sql for searching can be limiting.
4. The route will return the results (1 or more depends on what you want), then you just use jQuery to change the innerHtml of whatever element is displaying the name